# Not able to get document snapshot when I pass a variable as document reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

First of all, I am new to asking questions on stack overflow and would like to apologise for any mistakes while asking the question.

I am trying to get some data that I have in firebase firestore in node js. Here is the code:

```
firestoreDatabaseName
  .collection("collectionName")
  .doc(request.body.id)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      console.log(request.body.id);
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      response.send("Document found.");
    } else {
      console.log("Document doesn't exist", request.body.id);
      response.send("Document doesn't exist.");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

When I run the above code, the result that get's logged into the the console is: "Document doesn't exist 5TLopY8RCHeUZolA0d2v", 5TLopY8RCHeUZolA0d2v being the document reference id which I am passing through the variable "request.body.id". I have checked in the firestore and this document exists. Now when I run the above code by passing the same document reference id as string, I get the snapshot and the data. Here is the code that works:

```
firestoreDatabaseName
  .collection("collectionName")
  .doc("5TLopY8RCHeUZolA0d2v")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      response.send("Document found.");
    } else {
      response.send("Document doesn't exist.");
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

This code is able to log the data to the console successfully while the code above isn't, event though the document reference is same in both cases. Please help.

Comment: Can you console.log `request.body.id` just before your first code? Also I imagine that `collectionName`is just for illustration, right? Do you change it to the correct one in both cases?

Comment: @Oliver Yes oliver. "collectionNameis" is just for reference. I have the correct one in both the cases. I logged in request.body.id above as well, and it still has the value that I am passing which is "5TLopY8RCHeUZolA0d2v". I have done this many times before but never had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution and it was extremely stupid mistake on my behalf. It seems the id that I was passing as document reference had some white spaces at the end and when I used string.trim() it fixed the issue. Cheers